# '#' character before EL expression used inside a JSTL tag behaves strangely

Tags: java, string, jsp, jstl, el

I have the following code to set a userId variable:

(userId set in prior code)

```
<c:set var="userId" value="(Cust#${userId})" />
```

Which produces the following string: (Cust#${userId})

The following code works as expected, however:

```
<c:set var="userId" value="(Cust# ${userId})" />
```

displays the following string (Cust# 0001) .

Why does the '#' character before a '${string}' expression prevent the string from being evaluated? Is there a work around I could use that doesnt involve having to insert a space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since JSF would use:

```
#{userId}
```

To return a user Id, I would venture to guess that this is either a bug or expected behavior caused by the # sign making the parser unhappy.  Just use either of:

```
<c:set var="userId" value="(Cust&#35;${userId})" />
<c:set var="userId" >(Cust&#35;${userId})</c:set>
```

Comment: I think &pound; represents the currency symbol '£'. &#x0023; would be the Unicode entity '#'.

Answer (score 2):

I tested the above and it does not work. Its ouput would be:

Cust#0002 or whatever.

You can use an escape to get it to work right though. For example:

```
<c:set var="userId" value="(Cust\#${userId})" />
```

The output is:

Cust#0002